# Обращение к элементам родительского стиля XAML Silverlight

Tags: xaml

Допустим, что у меня есть следующий стиль:

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="MyType">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="MyType">
          <Grid>
             <Button x:Name="MyButton"/>
          </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

Можно ли унаследовать от него другой стиль и изменить в нем свойства кнопки "MyButton"?
Например изменить ее свойство Visibility?

Answer (score 1):

Можно.

Например, так:

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="MyType">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="InnerButtonStyle"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="MyType">
                <Grid>
                    <Button x:Name="MyButton"
                            Style="{DynamicResource InnerButtonStyle}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="MyModifiedStyle" TargetType="MyType"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="InnerButtonStyle">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Таким образом можно виртуализировать всё, что угодно.